# Saving django test database in a fixture?

Tags: python, django

I have a production database that contains a large set of data. I'd like to use some of that data for running unit tests, but taking all of it causes a fairly lengthy period at the start of the testing process to build the database., which I'd like to avoid.

I've created a test database using the `manage.py testserver` command, then deleted all the data I didn't want to be included through the admin interface. How do I create a fixture of the data that remains in the default test database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `dumpdata` to generate a json fixture, like this:

`./manage.py dumpdata > fixture.json`

if you want to save a fixture from your test, just serialize your qs:

```
# ... import your Models
from django.core.serializers import serialize


qs1 = Model1.objects.filter(...)
qs2 = Model2.objects.filter(...)
...

fixture = serialize('json', list(qs1) + list(qs2) + list(...))
with open('fixture.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fixture)
```

Comment: But doesn't that use the default database? Not the database automatically generated for running tests?

Comment: where do you create that testdatabase?

Comment: python manage.py testserver creates one automatically, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#testserver-fixture-fixture

Comment: no, I mean is your testdatabase sit along with your production one?

Comment: I have a local copy of the production database sitting on my development machine. I don't want to delete data from that one.

Comment: Wasn't quite get what you needed before, now answered edited. you can manually do it by serializing your queryset and write into json file.

Comment: @Bartvbl, glad it helps. Sorry I misunderstodd your question before

Answer (score 5):

Now it is easier to save the test data into a fixture.

When you run the django unittests, a `test` database is automatically created by putting `test_` before the name of the default database. We can make django aware of this database by creating a new database on `settings.py`. For example

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
        'NAME': 'test_mydatabase',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}
    }
}
```

Then run a unittest setting a breakpoint on the first line, edit the test database as you wish, then run the following command:

```
./manage.py dumpdata app_name -o filename.json --database test
```

This will dump all data in the `test` database into `filename`. Notice that you should edit the test database while the unittest is running (hence the breakpoint). If not, even if you preserve the test database all its data will be erased upon completion of the unit test.

Comment: With this approach, testcase will unnecessarily attempt to recreate the additional profile's database on run. I'm aware `test` is used to ensure we can `dumpdata`. But any other way to prevent this?

Comment: Hey @atjua, the idea is to only run the tests on the default database (which will in fact create the `test_mydatabase` database. If you ran the tests on the `test` database, a new database called `test_test_mydatabase` would be created (was this what you meant?). But, if you use the `test` database just for dumping data, new databases shouldn't be created...

Comment: @atjua you need to use `MIRROR` in config of your second database

Comment: NOTE this doesn't work unless you use TransactionTestCase. If you use TestCase you will get no output from dump_data because all of the edits to the database will be trapped in a transaction and will never be committed.